# Angular js directive to show alert for browser back button when unsaved data in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a newbie to angularjs.Is there any way to show alert when a form has unsaved data and user presses browser back button.
Any pointers to how to achieve this would be appreciated.

**Update: :**

```
    angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('confirmOnExit', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {


            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

                if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                    if(!confirm("Ahh the form is dirty, do u want to continue?")) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });

            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                alert('me');
                if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                    return "The Form is Dirty.";
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**Updated code**

```
    angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('confirmOnExit', function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, $rootScope) {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                    return " do you want to stay on the page?";
                }
            }

            $rootScope.$watch(function {
                return $location.path();
            },

            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue != oldvalue) {
                    // here you can do your tasks
                } else {}
            },
            true);

            $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
                if ($scope.myForm.$dirty) {
                    if (!confirm("The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?")) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I just gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890784/fire-a-callback-when-route-is-changed-animations-loaders-stacking-different-v/14893923#14893923) some minutes ago to another user, create a watch at root scope level to catch location changing:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() { // fixed function declaration
   return $location.path();
   },  
   function(newValue, oldValue) {  
      if (newValue != oldValue) { // Update: variable name case should be the same
         // here you can do your tasks
      }
      else {
      }
   },
   true);
```

Comment: well i'm new to angular js so can u tell me where should i put this angularjs, in directive or controller portion,i'll post my existing code.Plz have a look

Comment: Just put the watch in the directive controller instead of the root scope

Comment: i just did dat but it shows error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return  at return $location.path()

Comment: i just updated the modified code as per ur suggestion above.Have a look

Comment: Exactly, anyway this is not the right place to chat, if you need further advise let's go to the chatroom.

Comment: Look at the definition of $watch on the angular [API doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope), it's a callback, Angular calls it with the old and new values of the watched variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24586/discussion-between-remigio-and-iblue)

Comment: here is a better solution to detect browser back button: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686169/angularjs-redirect-a-route-only-on-browsers-back-button

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, you can write a custom directive to watch for changes. Your updated code is on track, however there are a few things you could do to improve:

1. Your directive references the form by name, which limits it's re-usability. For example, what if you wanted to use this same directive on a form called `myOtherForm`? Currently using `$scope.myForm.$dirty` limits this flexibility. Instead, a better approach is to bind to the formController in your linking function.
2. There really isn't a need to watch `$location.path()` since binding to `$locationChangeStart` will do the same thing.

I've written an angularjs directive that you can uses the approaches I've discussed above. @see https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges

Hopefully you find this directive informative. Feel free to learn from it or even use it in your project.