# Misleading breadcrumbs when using back-button with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, caching, angularjs, breadcrumbs

I'm using the [ngBreadcrumbs-Service from Enrico Pulatzo](https://github.com/enricopulatzo/ng-breadcrumbs) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enricopulatzo/CY37S/)). Pushing breadcrumbs and unregistering works fine as long as the user clicks on the breadcrumb. However, if the back-button or another link is used, the breadcrumbs don't get updated and show the last entry twice when following a new route. How can I change this behavior to always have the correct breadcrumb trail?

```
Home > Users
```

After clicking users and navigating back. Breadcrumbs should only include 'Home'.

```
Home > Users > Users
```

After clicking users, navigating back and clicking users again.

Comment: Look's like it only supports and mentions it removes when you click, might be worth opening an issue on the GitHub project for clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a $location.path watcher [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893867/angular-js-directive-to-show-alert-for-browser-back-button-when-unsaved-data-in) to reduce the array holing the breadcrumbs, now everything works as expected.

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return $location.path();
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        if (newValue.split('/').length < oldValue.split('/').length) {
            data.splice(1, data.length);
  }
        $rootScope.$broadcast('breadcrumbsRefresh');
    }
}, true);
```