# AngularJS redirect a route only on browser's back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, back, angularjs-routing

In my AngularJS application I'm redirecting the `route` to a specific page when the user isn't logged. To do that I'm using a variable on `$rootScope`.

Now I would like to prevent the browser's back button when the user is logged.  I would like to redirect it to a specific page (the `registration` view). The problem is I don't know if there's a *back button event*.

My code is:

```
 angular.module('myApp',[...]
//Route configurations
}])
.run(function($rootScope, $location){
               $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
                   if(!$rootScope.loggedUser) { 
                       $location.path('/register');
                   }
               });
               $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
                   console.log("Current: " + current);
                   console.log("Next: " + next);
               });
           });
```

So on `$locationChangeStart` I would write a pseudocode like:

```
if (event == backButton){
     $location.path('/register');
}
```

Is it possible?

A naive solution would be writing a function that checks if `next` and `current` are in the wrong order, detecting if the user is *going back*.

There are other solutions? I'm approaching the problem in a wrong way?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Why block the back button if the route will be redirected?

Comment: I want to block the default behaviour of the back button, redirecting it to the first page of my application, when the user is logged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution, which is easier than I thought. I register on a object in `$rootScope` the actual location and on every location change I check with the new one. In this way I can detect if the user is going back in the history.

```
angular.module('myApp',[...], {
    //Route configurations
}])
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if(!$rootScope.loggedUser) { 
            $location.path('/register');
        }
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
        $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
    });

    $rootScope.$watch(function() { return $location.path() },
        function(newLocation, oldLocation) {
            if($rootScope.actualLocation == newLocation) {
                $location.path('/register');
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```