# how to force page load from server javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i am back through the browser back button it will not refreshed but it is from cache of browsers.

i want to reload the page from server while click Back button of browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899274/how-to-refresh-page-on-back-button-click

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686169/angularjs-redirect-a-route-only-on-browsers-back-button catch moving back and then `$location.reload()`

Comment: `$route.reload()` this one reloading

Answer (score 0):

first you can check if user going back like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705493/4104866
and then you can refresh

```
 angular.module('myApp',[...,'ngRoute']
//Route configurations
}])
.run(function($rootScope,$route, $location){

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){
        $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
    });

    $rootScope.$watch(function() {return $location.path()}, function(newLocation, oldLocation){
        if($rootScope.actualLocation == newLocation){
            //user going back
              $route.reload();
        }
    });

           });
```

refresh `$route.reload`