# How to avoid showing login page if already logged on with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application with AngularJS. I have authentication working and when the user is not authorized, he gets redirected to `#/login` which shows a login form.

However, when the user is authenticated and he manually goes to `#/login`, the login page is shown again, although the user is still logged in. Is there any way to direct him to the home page in that case?

This is how I do the redirections:

```
$routeProvider
       .when( '/ds', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/datasheets-list.html',
            controller: 'DatasheetsListCtrl'
        } )
        .when( '/ds/:datasheetId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/datasheet-detail.html',
            controller: 'DatasheetDetailCtrl'
         } )                             
         .when( '/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
          } )
         .otherwise( {
            redirectTo: '/ds'
          } );
```

This is the code for the `LoginController`:

```
var datasheetsControllers = angular.module( 'datasheetsControllers', ['ngCookies', 'datasheetsServices'] );

datasheetsControllers.controller( 'LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', '$cookieStore', 'LoginService', function ( $scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, $cookieStore, LoginService )
{

    $scope.login = function ()
    {
        LoginService.authenticate( $.param( {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password} ), function ( user )
        {
            $rootScope.user = user;
            // Authenticate AngularJS Ajax calls
            $http.defaults.headers.common[ xAuthTokenHeaderName ] = user.token;

            // Authenticate jQuery Ajax calls
            var headers = {};
            headers[xAuthTokenHeaderName] = user.token;
            $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: headers
                        });
            $cookieStore.put( 'user', user );
            $location.path( "/" );
        } );
    };
}] );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the common practice is to listen to the `$routeChangeStart` event.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(scope, next, current){
   //...
});
```

here you can ask if the next path is login and then you can check for the auth service if the user is already logged in. if he is, use redirect as usual to redirect him directly to the login

alternativally you can use the `resolve` callback in your route object

```
when('/login', { controller: 'LoginCtrl', templateUrl: '', resolve : {
    load : function ( ... ) { ... }
})
```

There is already similar stuff here on SO

[AngularJS - Need some combination of $routeChangeStart and $locationChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978990/angularjs-need-some-combination-of-routechangestart-and-locationchangestart)

[Fire a callback when route is changed (animations, loaders etc) in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890784/fire-a-callback-when-route-is-changed-animations-loaders-etc-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by simply adding this to the `LoginController`:

```
if( $rootScope.user )
{
    $location.path( "/" );
}
```

(Just before the `$scope.login = function ()` line)

This seems to be working fine, but I don't know if it is considered a bad practice doing this?

Comment: While there is not a "problem" with this solution, you actually want to prevent the initialisation of the login page and everything attached to it, as the user should not even get there anymore. You can do that as mentioned by Luke, by listening to route change events.

Comment: In my opinion If you are not confident about the solution and still has a question like *" don't know if it is considered a bad practice doing this?"* ... it's better to add this as an update in the question itself.