# AngularJs - Skip login page if already logged in

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have implemented an Authentication system for my app. I use `$routeChangeStart` (in run) to check if the user is logged in and redirect him to login if not. This works fine. But, I can access the login page via the url, I want to send the user to the dashboard if he's already logged in. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Check if the user is already logged inside the $routeChangeStart and redirect it if necessary

Comment: I'm already using that! But how do I check if I'm loading up the login page itself?

Comment: Okay, $locationChangeStart works, thanks! But if this the standard way of doing what I'm trying?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid showing login page if already logged on with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876817/how-to-avoid-showing-login-page-if-already-logged-on-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {});
```

Details here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Answer (score 1):

Guys try this elegant solution:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, authService) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
            if (to.requireAuth && !authService.isAuthed()) {
                $location.path("/login");
            }
            else if (to.name == 'login' && authService.isAuthed()) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                $location.path("/dashboard");
            }
        });
    })
```

- if the user is not logged in and login is required it redirect to
  login.
- if the user try to get to login and he already logged in,
  prevent him from doing it.
- mark every path as "requireAuth" and it
  will work.
- place your code in app.js