# AngularJS specific HTML on route suffix

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a simple gallery with Angular and I am trying to have a template shown on some route, which is very easy with angular.

```
some.site/#/gallery
```

is done with

```
App.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/gallery', {
                templateUrl: 'js/views/gallery/main.htm',
                controller: 'galleryCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'gallery'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
]);
```

But then I want to have a div popup when user clicks on thing and goes to

```
some.site/#/gallery/thing/1
```

Note that I still want my gallery to be on the background.

My initial idea was to have that div always hidden unless there's `*/thing` so that I could just get the id like so `*/thing/:id` when needed, but this approach seems rather ugly, because why have that thing hanging in there all the time?

Are there any other, better ways of doing that?

Comment: still unclear with your requirement without HTML code.

Comment: maybe you can hook into the [global route change events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009419/36938) and check for `/#/gallery/thing/1` there to toggle the popup? just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set a $routeParam depending on your route, let's say:

- if url is /gallery, then 'showPopup' = false
- if url is /gallery/thing/:id, then 'showPopup' = true

and then in your html you bind the popup state to $routeParams.showPopup.

To do so, you can set the params directly in your mapping:

```
App.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/gallery', {
            templateUrl: 'js/views/gallery/main.htm',
            controller: 'galleryCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'gallery',
            resolve: {
              ignored: function ($route) { 
                 $route.current.params.showPopup = false; 
               }
            }
        })
        .when('/gallery/thing/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'js/views/gallery/main.htm',
            controller: 'galleryCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'gallery',
            resolve: {
              ignored: function ($route) { 
                 $route.current.params.showPopup = true; 
               }
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }
]);
```

Hope I helped !

Comment: i ended up doing pretty much the same thing, though after rethinking the architecture of my routing i didn't need to 'hide' that variable in $routeParams. Your method is pretty useful in other circumstances, so thanks again)

Comment: You're welcome ! If it answers your question, I encourage you to accept the answer (by clicking the green tick) so that other users knows there is a solution to the question you ask.